# Ubuntu Core Kiosk wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk

Tags: ubuntu-core, kiosk

I managed to get a Ubuntu Core-based kiosk working with a full-screen web-browser by following this tutorial: https://mir-server.io/docs/make-a-secure-ubuntu-web-kiosk

I used the **ubuntu-frame** and **wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk** snaps.

The problem I have now is that the background is black and on most websites, this causes some very strange rendering. I'm not sure if this is a ubuntu-frame issue or a wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk issue.

I tried editing the background colour settings of ubuntu-frame, but that didn't make any difference. I set it to white and as soon as the website loaded it all became black. So I suspect maybe it could be **wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk**.

I have attached an example of LinkedIn which shows view in kiosk and on normal desktop browser compared.

Does anyone know what this could be?

Some pictures below:

[In Kiosk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFSbN.jpg)

[On normal computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VgaM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a fix is imminent. You will be able to set the default background color to white (for example) using bg-color=white.

See the original related issues in the repo here:

https://gitlab.com/glancr/wpe-webkit-snap/-/issues/36
https://gitlab.com/glancr/wpe-webkit-snap/-/issues/46